# How can I get through mac firewall to let my mobile device access webpack dev server?

Tags: networking, firewall, webpack-dev-server, ports, macos-high-sierra

I have a dev server running in an Angular 5 cli-project at localhost:4200 through webpack-dev-server.

I want to connect my iphone to the dev server for testing. It uses the same wifi SSID as my computer.

I'm using the computer's registered name in safari's url field in the iphone:

```
jonathans-macbook-pro.local:4200
```

It doesn't work and after waiting it says

> Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding

I also have the [coda](https://panic.com/coda/) app that also serves a project at

```
jonathans-macbook-pro.local:62035
```

and I'm able to access it just fine on the Safari browser. Although this is because I believe I can allow the coda app to accept incoming connections:

[image: Allow Coda]

Although I'm not sure how to get more technical other than adding an application through the GUI. I've tried to using editing the PF rules at /etc/pf.conf

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 80
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 4200
```

and then did:

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

to reload it. Although the iphone still can't connect to the localhost:4200 dev server.

---

I also had hopped that allowing **node** to accept incoming connections (via a popup) would allow the iphone to get through the firewall, although it still doesn't work.

[image]

Anyone have any idea what could be preventing my iPhone from connecting to the dev-server on my mac?